# CakePHP sanitize line feed \n

Tags: cakephp, line, feed, sanitization, sanitize

I have a comment box and when somebody presses enter, Cake will put a \n (line feed) into the database. When I retrieve this from the db, it is displayed just like \n instead of an actual break or in HTML a 
.

There seems to be no option for handling \n, which I cannot understand because it is common to push enter in a textarea. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks 
Chris

Comment: Could you post some code? I use CakePHP and I've never run into this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget that there are php functions covering that :)
nl2br() is what you are looking for

```
echo nl2br(h($data));
```

NOTE:

- h() is for security reasons. always use h() first, than nl2br().
- you dont need h() if you have html content. h() is only for plain text.
- TIP: you can even enhance your bake templates to automatically display it correctly - see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/22/cake-bake-custom-templates/ for details

Comment: it should also be noted that the new cake version in 2.x automatically use h() in all baked templates now.

Comment: and you can customize your bake templates to automatically add nl2br() for all textarea outputs, as well (view, index pages).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try
`echo str_replace("\\n", "<br />", $variable);`

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has it's own method for that:

```
TextHelper::autoParagraph(string $text)
```

Check the documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html